# what is the impact of escaped characters on seo-friendly urls?

Tags: seo

I have a site that displays products - in the simplest sense the url of the page for a particular product is:

site.com/products/manufacturer_model - so for example if I was displaying a Dell Latitude D700 laptop my URL would look like:

site.com/products/dell_latitude_d700

I have a number of products that contain characters that I would need to URL escape - so for example a Dell Latitude 12?34.  Obviously I cannot include the '?' character in the URL.  For the purpose of being SEO-friendly - should I ignore that character? e.g.

site.com/products/dell_latitude_1234

Or should I escape it? e.g.

site.com/products/dell_latitude_12%3F34

Seems like escaping it would be the most logical approach - but do crawlers understand this?

Answer (score 0):

Well, using "_" is not so friendly to users, so I think using "-" is better (check seoMOZ beginners guide).

Also, you would like to check what characters really need escaping on [RFC 3986](http://www.apps.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.html). If you are using PHP, check out urlencode function page at php.net. I wrote a function to make this updated conversion a few months ago ;)

But getting back to your main question, do use escaped (when needed per RFC 3986) for writing your URLs. It is the safe path to not getting stuck or penalized.